# Is it possible to run a Neo4j cluster with strong consistency?

Tags: neo4j, cluster-computing, consistency

[The docs of Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-architecture.html) state that when running in HA mode, you get eventual consistency. This is a quote from that page:

> All updates will however propagate from the master to other slaves
>   eventually so a write from one slave may not be immediately visible on
>   all other slaves

My question is: is there a configuration that will allow me to write a cluster with strong consistency, of course at the cost of reduced performance? I'm looking for some sort of active-passive failover cluster configuration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is such an config option. `ha.tx_push_factor` determines to how many slaves a transaction should be pushed to synchronously. When setting this to `ha.tx_push_factor=<clustersize>-1` you have immediate full consistency.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if one of the slaves is unavailable? Would the transaction fail, rendering the cluster useless?

Comment: no, the transaction will success. `ha.tx_push_factor` is used on a best effort basis. If a slave is down for some time it will sync up with the cluster when joining again.

Comment: Is it possible to set pull interval to 0, causing immediate pulls by the slave from the master?
Best effort isn't good enough for us, as we need to be able to read back our own writes reliably.

Comment: don't set pull interval too low - not sure what happens in case of null.

Comment: OK, can you confirm that the push really is synchronous? So unless there is a communication problem, I am guaranteed consistency?

Comment: Yes I did a week of hard testing the HA mode last week, there is 100% consistency. Just for info if you do not use HA proxy, if the master goes down, a slave will be elected as master, when the previous master come back to life he is not reelected as master again, so you'll have to do checks on the /ha endoint

Comment: @StefanArmbruster But if instead of a node down, a network partition occurs. One side of the cluster will be not up to date but will it be responding for read requests? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly. Writes are synchronized with the master which needs to have a quorum. If you're in a minority network partition, quorum is not reached, therefore no master. No master, no writes. Degrading to read-only.

Comment: This parameter is optimistic. Neo4j can mark Tx as succeeded even if some pushes failed.